# TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, poo

Estoy desarrollando un pequeño ejercicio de la implementación de una clase orientada a manejo de fracciones con sus respectivos metodos, luego debo usarla para hacer una pequeña calculadora, el módulo con la clase funciona perfecto y he probado cada uno de los métodos por separado. En otro archivo, importo el módulo y la ocupo para hacer el programa, en modo de resumen, copio el código:

```
a=Fraccion(raw_input("n/n?"))
b=Fraccion(raw_input("n/n?"))
print(str(a+b))
```

Las funciones creadas en la clase Fraccion, que son ocupadas en este pequeño extracto son:

```
#entrega la suma de dos fracciones
def __add__(self,x):
    num=self.__numerador * x.__denominador + self.__denominador * x.__numerador
    den=self.__denominador * x.__denominador
    return Fraccion(num,den).simple()

#entrega una fraccion representada en string
def __str__(self):
    return str(self.__numerador) + '/' + str(self.__denominador)
```

El error exacto es:

```
File "/Users/xxxxxxxxx/PycharmProjects/untitled/clase16.py", line 43,     in __add__
num=self.__numerador * x.__denominador + self.__denominador * x.__numerador
TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'str'
```

Muchas gracias por la ayuda:)

**[Actualización]:**

```
class Fraccion:
    # ...
    def __init__(self, x=0, y=1): 
        if type(x)==str: 
            i=x.find("/") 
            self.__numerador=x[0:i] 
            self.__denominador=x[i+1:] 
        else: 
            self.__numerador=x 
            self.__denominador=y 
            assert self.__denominador!=0
    # ...
```

Comment: puedes mostrar el constructor de la clase?

Comment: Deberias incluir como te dice eyllanesc el **constructor** de tu clase `Fraccion` porque parece que el problema está en los atributos `__numerador`  y `__denominador` por conflicto de tipos de datos. En teoría deberian ser `int` ambos.

Answer (score 1):

Parece que `objeto.__numerador` u `objeto.__denominador` son secuencias y cadenas. Es decir, estás mezclando tipos y una secuencia no se puede multiplicar con una cadena. Si enseñas el inicializador o el código completo de la clase `Fracción` podríamos conocer dónde se produce exactamente el error.

Por otra parte, usas la etiqueta [python-3.x](/questions/tagged/python-3.x) pero `raw_input` no funciona en python 3.

**[Actualización]**

Varias cosas:

- Si en el método `__init__` defines una forma de introducir valores no te la saltes a la torera. Si quieres tener libertad podrías usar `*args` o `**kwargs`.
- Tal cual está tú método `__init__` tanto `obj.__numerador` como `obj.__denominador` son cadenas y las estás multiplicando por otras cadenas. Para que funcione el operador suma debes convertir en números tanto `obj.__numerador` como `obj.__denominador` para poder operar con ellos como números. Para representarlos en pantalla define correctamente un método `__str__`.

Yo lo definiría de la siguiente forma:

```
class Fraccion:

    def __init__(self, x=0, y=1): 
        # Aquí podrías hacer alguna comprobación 
        # para ver si x e y son enteros
        self.__numerador=x 
        if y != 0:
            self.__denominador=y
        else:
            raise ZeroDivisionError('Estás dividiendo por cero')

    def __add__(self, x):
        num = self.__numerador * x.__denominador + self.__denominador * x.__numerador
        den = self.__denominador * x.__denominador
        #############
        ## No sé cual es el método simple por lo que el return no lo modifico
        #############
        return Fraccion(num,den).simple()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.__numerador) + '/' + str(self.__denominador)
```

Comment: def __init__(self, x=0, y=1):
      if type(x)==str:
          i=x.find("/")
          self.__numerador=x[0:i]
          self.__denominador=x[i+1:]
      else:
          self.__numerador=x
          self.__denominador=y
      assert self.__denominador!=0

Ese es el código del constructor

Comment: @RudyGarcia he modificado la respuesta a ver si te sirve.